# Advice on determining close locations while iPhone app in background

Tags: iphone, core-location, background-process

I need some advice for a location based iPhone app.

I'm building an app that informs the user of nearby locations. When the app is in the foreground it will use the normal didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: method (calculates distance between user and place of interest), but when it is in the background I'm not sure what is the best way to do this.

I'm thinking of creating CLRegions from all the places of interest just before the app goes to the background. If the user enters a region the app will do a local notification and inform the user of the place of interest.

Or I could register for CL significant update, calc distance between user and all the places and notify of any close ones. Maybe not the best solution, the OS might not give me enough time to compute close places?

Has anyone any experience doing the same? any advice?

Comment: I don't work with iPhones, but from a design point of view I would say that you should be as uninvasive as possible when the device is in the background. You should only warn about the highest priority places of interest, preferably only if they're within a small range. Depending on what you're doing, you could perhaps draw on some sort of review or census system to specify which are the most important or popular locations.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Polynomial that will be indeed a concern after I've resolved this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should register for significant locations updates (cell change events), and then do your math on events. You can do anything on the basis of this event. As per my experience, region monitoring is also dependent on cell change events along with some extra computations which you don't need.

However you need to enable background location updates. For which you need to convince Apple that this background location services are required for your app. As Apple docs say that background location services are only for apps who provide turn by turn navigation.

how to enable background location updating
[Understanding background tracking of user's location in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053859/understanding-background-tracking-of-users-location-in-ios/15224014#15224014)