# Running async operation after location update in background

Tags: ios, asynchronous, sdk, location

I'm trying to understand the life-cycle of an app when we need to do a background update to our servers in response to a location manager update.

We are tracking the user's location every 1km and we need to report the location back to our servers as each update arrives to us. If we fail to send it is cached in core data and included in the next update as necessary.

However, we are not sure of the life-cycle of the operation. The app is woken up from the background when the update arrives but as we are starting an asynchronous HTTP operation based on that using AFNetworking we are a little nervous of how that asynchronous operation will behave as regarding the app being made inactive again while in the middle of the asynch operation.

I understand we can ask for grace time by using the `[operation  setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler]` as part of AFNetworking which should work ok.

However, will this carry over into future iOS updates?

Thanks for any insights on how this works...

Comment: So you are looking to keep the app sending data while it is in the background?

Comment: only to send the update. Basically, one update per location update in ideal conditions. If it fails it batch uploads previously unsent locations.

Comment: Hmmm, but FYI the application stay only 10 mins in the background, after that you will lose the communication.

Comment: yes, but the http operation should be a few hundred ms in good conditions. Maybe seconds. My concern is that in future iOS updates the grace time may be undefined... or be coalesced...

Comment: If the application in the background for more than 10 mins then you can't get that update from it, this is what I mean, for iOS updates there will be significant changes in background tasks and multitasking.

Comment: Every time the user moves 1km we get some processing time via the didUpdateToLocation callback as we are using the location background mode. But is doing asynch operations from there safe? What happens if I don't ask for grace time?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, in `didUpdateToLocation` method you can perform any thing, so try there will be no harm. I also suggest to check this question:

[Understanding background tracking of user's location in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053859/understanding-background-tracking-of-users-location-in-ios/15224014#15224014)

Beside for the iOS7, luckily there will be significant improvement in the background and multi tasking, from [Apple's developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios7/):

> Keep the content of your app up-to-date by adopting the new
>   multitasking APIs in iOS 7. The new services allow your app to update
>   information and download content in the background without draining
>   the battery unnecessarily. The updates can happen at opportunistic
>   times and are intelligently scheduled according to usage, so your app
>   can update content in the background just when your users need it.

But it is under NDA now, so I suggest to login to developer forum and read about that.

Comment: The correct procedure in iOS6 is as suggested in my question and in your reference. However, I'm worried about how a background AFnetworking thread will run if started from didUpdateToLocation on iOS7. Is it possible it can get put to inactive state while comms are sending the HTTP request to our server. I'm aware of the NDA so if I posted this in the dev forums can you give more insights there? It's pretty lacking there compare to here.

Comment: I guess my question is, is it mandatory to use the new iOS7 way? I know AFnetworking 2.0 has added support.

Comment: No it is not mandatory, If i were you, i would give it a try in xCode5 and ios7 beta ;) .